# Using established domain names and phrases in your sentences as a keywords to boost your rank?

Tags: seo, keywords

Let's imagine a situation. I run a company that sells trucks and my nearest webrank competitors are websites called "reliableblacktrucks.com" and "trucksreallycheap.net".

Could I potentially tap into their search egine space by using a sentences like "We do not sell only reliable black trucks, but also we can offer you those trucks really cheap" and so on? Just a food for though I had.

Comment: You can tap into different keyword spaces with external signals, no need to ruin your pages with mindless keyword based sentences that destroy user experience. Always write your content for your users, not the search engines.

Comment: Real search competition starts with knowing what search users are *really* searching for and NOT what you or anyone else *thinks* they are searching for. For example, the most overused term by SEOs is *best* which is only primarily searched by SEOs and not users. Think back to when you entered the search term *best* for any search. People do not search using therms such as *reliable* or *cheap*. Think about how people really search and start there. Otherwise, all of your SEO efforts will be based upon purely unfiltered bull squirt. Go back to basics and win the war that way.

Comment: As a side note, terms do not increase rank, other factors will do that. Terms used properly within the context of whole language matches search intent which in time will allow a site to rank for specific searches. Otherwise, rank comes from search success, quality links, and trust metrics rather than specific terms squeezed in here and there. Keep in mind if search was about keywords, it would all be far too easy and any site would compete regardless if merit.

Comment: @closetnoc, in fact good businesses don't use cheap... affordable maybe... but certainly not cheap :)

Comment: @SimonHayter Precisely my point. People often chase what they think are important terms when in fact, what people search for is much more plain and simple. If I were to chase terms, it would related to the topic and not necessarily an adjective unless absolutely necessary such as for specific products for sale, etc. It all depends on the goal of course! Still, I would limit the adjectives as not to limit search. Too much is too much. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc You really do have some great comments. You should post them as answers more - I would totally upvote. Your three comments here would make a great answer (much better than the answer currently posted). :)

Comment: @TimMalone Cheers mate!! I appreciate that! I tried to write a decent answer, however, I did not want to go into the usual semantics detail and worked off of the examples from the OP. I am in a kinda sleepy mood today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you should know.

1] Most websites are poorly optimized.

2] Most sites with SEO help are still poorly optimized.

3] Terms found in a URL domain name are significant.

4] Terms found within content can easily overcome the lack of the same terms within the URL domain name.

5] Keywords, in of themselves, is not how search works.

6] Most keywords people chase are not actually used in search.

Most of the time, it does not pay to try and compete directly against another web site because most are not optimized well. Playing catch-up and competing directly against a poorly optimized website often leads you in the wrong direction.

*What matters is how people **actually** search.*

It is difficult to figure out what people search for. Many SEOs will swear by certain keywords. In my comments, I lament the use of the term *best* by SEOs when in fact, most people do not use the term to search. When was the last time you entered the term *best* in a search query? You may very well never have. And that is the point. Do a search for *best chocolate chip cookie* and the results will be staggering. The number of sites that try and compete for a useless search term makes the useless search term effectiveness completely moot.

Search is about whole language. RankBrain and Google's index are semantic based and not term based. In otherwords, semantics is used to *understand* the query and any site/page topic and make an appropriate match. It is not a search term match, it is a semantics topic match along with syntactic analysis. The analysis gets very deep indeed, however, I will not be going into that here. I have written about semantics in enough other answers you can read them if you want.

One of the things people do not realize is that certain terms are less effective in search for some sites. I used the example of adjectives in my comments. Adjectives are important, however, they are often less important in search with some exception. For example, a *red* car makes it clear that adjectives are important. However, when was the last time you searched for a *red* anything? This example dove-tails into your examples which I realize are just off the top of your head. Granted. In your example, *black* and *cheap* are likely fairly useless. Anyone searching for a car will likely not use these terms. For this reason, these are likely useless terms for a URL domain name.

*If you were to search for a car, what would you search for?*

This is the toughest nut to crack. Ask a few friends to do searches on the net and keep track of what search queries they use and what SERP links and snippets they preferred. What you will likely find is that the searches are simple, short, and devoid of adjectives except for a few. You can give them specific tasks such as finding a low-cost black pick-up truck. Be careful not to implant into their minds search term suggestions that may skew the results.

You can use the SERP links and snippets to better understand why these sites stand out. Do not do this yourself. It is okay to be around and ask questions as your friends search. You may learn more that way.

What you may find is that regardless of the use of the search term *black*, the results may not yield results for a black pick-up truck.

For example, yesterday, I was searching for Triumph motorcycles. I was looking for dealers specifically. I was looking for specific years and models and other specific information. Most all of my searches did not result in what I was looking for. For example, I did not find one dealer but primarily websites that people use to post their ad to sell their motorcycle. I found one dealer that had not sold Triumphs in years and did not contain the term *triumph* on their site at all. As well, searching for models worked fairly well. Year did not. Many of my results often showed Harley Davidson motorcycles and not Triumphs. As well, since I was looking for an older Triumph, mostly new Triumphs were shown regardless of what I did. Even then, not one of them was *cheap*. All results were for premium priced Triumphs well over the market value. Very frustrating for someone who simply wants a reliable older Triumph from a reputable dealer at a reasonable price. The terms reliable, older, reasonable, vintage, used, pre-owned, etc., all were relatively useless.

For the record, E-commerce sites are a bit different. You will find adjectives within the product page/description and not within a domain name, path, file name, etc. This is an important point because this is not where you would expect to find them. If you are trying to boost performance for an e-commerce site, you will be working a bit differently than for a blog.

Using your example, adjectives can better perform within the h1 or lesser header tag, the product description, and within any store-front form element. As well, I discovered that using a few h3 and h4 header tags can weigh fairly heavily if done well. For example, for a list of products, the lower header tags can contain details such as color etc. H2 tags are often used for this. Adding an appropriate h3 header along with a paragraph tag below each h2 may help.

What you do will depend upon your site. I am not suggesting using header tags to boost search results for every situation. I was just using that as an example.

What is important is to use whole language. If you are selling a black pick-up truck, then say so. For example, *Chevy 1500 pick-up truck, black exterior, black interior with 5.0 liter v8 engine and automatic transmission. Best in class fuel efficiency and towing.* within a header tag should help. These content elements should appear elsewhere such as within a product description paragraph below the header tag to support the semantic weight.

However, this is not the end of the story. Site trust metrics and quality organic links as well as many other metrics such as CTR (click-through rate) and bounce rate also influence search.

This is how sites compete in search.

Without a realistic example, I cannot give good solid advice on how better to compete. Hypothetical scenarios do not always lend themselves to better answers. Sorry. Hopefully, I gave you some ideas anyhow.

Comment: Pretty thorough answer and well written, thanks, changed how I think about web optimization a lot actually

Answer (score 1):

You could tap into their search engine space by using the same sorts of keywords that they use - but keywords are only one aspect of SEO.

If they have more established sites with high quality content and higher quality backlinks, it will be safe to assume that for a little while their sites will rank higher than yours in the Google index.

It is also important to ensure that whatever keywords you use are appropriate to your site and your business, as Google can and does detect false keywords and ignore them.